# Populate Form Collection (for edit/update) Zend Framework 2

Tags: forms, zend-framework2, formcollection

I have successfully created a Zf2 Form Collection for use as line items in an invoice model. There are 2 tables, invoice and lineitems, one form. The collection displays fine in the form, I can dynamically add them with javascript, and I can save the individual fieldsets by using the standard TableGateway implementation, iterating over the sub array in the add action.

Here is where I get stuck -

How do I populate (or Hydrate) the collection for editing/updating/viewing purposes?

Is there a built in mechanism to know how many fieldsets there are in the collection?

Say the collection is initially set for 2 fieldsets and one is added dynamically, how does the edit action (or form) know how many fieldsets are in the collection?

I have been using Celtico's QuAdmin as a base for this project - https://github.com/Celtico/QuAdmin

Also been looking over - https://github.com/rlandas/zf2-zendformcollections

Again any help would be appreciated and If you need any code let me know. Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any specific issues with this? For me yes it just works. Forms are hydrated with the correct amount of fieldsets

Comment: I will test it in a seperate module as QuAdmin might be messing me up. How did you get the collection to work? Was it based on the documentation?